# Getting a web users location for DateTime CultureInfo conversion

Tags: datetime, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, utc, cultureinfo

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and am deploying this application to Azure. All DateTime values are stored in UTC format.

How is the best way to display these values as local time for the web user? I know how to convert a UTC DateTime to LocalTime, yet am not sure on the best way to display these DateTime values to international users that are using the Azure website.

I have done some research and I have read that the following can be done:

1. Get the HttpRequest.UserLanguages string array.
2. Retrieve its first element. The first element indicates the user's default or preferred language and region.
3. Instantiate a CultureInfo object that represents the user's preferred culture by calling the CultureInfo.CultureInfo(String, Boolean) constructor.
4. Convert the UTC DateTime using the CultureInfo object.

Is there a better/easier way to do this? Does this have to be done in each controller/action result, or can this be done in one place? Has anyone written some code that I can use rather than writing my own code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your web config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you are not planing to use localized resources then you can omit the `uiCulture` part of the config.

> This setting automatically switches the ASP.NET request to the browser
>   client’s language if a match can be found. If the browser doesn’t
>   provide a language or the language can’t be matched to one of the .NET
>   installed cultures, the fallback value is used – in this case en-US.
>
> This setting applies the ASP.NET request thread’s CurrentCulture and
>   UICulture. The culture is switched very early in the ASP.NET
>   HttpApplication lifecycle, so you see the selected culture applied and
>   available even in Application_BeginRequest and then throughout the
>   rest of the request cycle.

[The full article about this](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/27/Auto-Selecting-Cultures-for-Localization-in-ASPNET)